# HOW do i see content of rails cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hii all,
          i would like to know is there any way to view rails cache content??

Comment: Which cache are you asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need read it

```
Rails.cache.read('yourkey')
```

Comment: but am using rails 2.2 version it is possible to do in rails 2.2

Comment: See the full docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html - there is no way to list all keys.