# Way to examine contents of Rails cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to debug stale entries in a cached view in a Rails (5.0.0.beta2) running on Heroku. I'd like to look at the entries in the cache to confirm that they are named the way that I expect and are getting expired when they should.

Is there any way to do this? I found this question, [HOW do i see content of rails cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760702/how-do-i-see-content-of-rails-cache), which suggests `Rails.cache.read("your_key")`. So, using `bin/rails c` (on Heroku) I tried:

```
Rails.cache.read(User.find(19).cache_key) => nil
```

Where 19 is the `:id` of one of the users for whom I'm seeing stale data. This has me kind of stumped...

If I try:

```
User.find(19).cache_key => "users/19-20160316151228266421"
```

But when a cache entry is supposedly expired the log line looks like:

```
Expire fragment views/users/19-20160316151228266421 (0.2ms)
```

So I tried doing a `Rails.cache.read` on that path, this also returned `nil` – I also tried doing the same with a user that had not be expired, and got `nil` again.

I'm wondering if that difference in path signals a problem, or if there is a way to see the path of the key that is created (I've been assuming that it matches at least the part after the slash).

Comment: Did you try `Rails.cache.read('views/users/19-20160316151228266421')`?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I did. That also get's me `nil`. I also tried it with a user that has not been expired.

Answer (score 8):

Cache has the following instance variables:

```
[:@options, :@data, :@key_access, :@max_size, :@max_prune_time, :@cache_size, :@monitor, :@pruning]
```

You can examine the data with:

```
Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data)
```